# After updating from 9.10 to 10.04 everything is great except Grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub, ubuntu-10.04

After the update I have absolutely no problem with Linux, but Grub doesn't let me start Windows any more. (Entry is there but I only get the flashing hyphen and nothing else happens)

Can I safely run "update grub" without damage to the Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo update-grub` will do the job I guess. :) (In a nutshell, yes you can. >.>)
Corrected the 'update grub' line in my answer ... thanks Quack.

Comment: no need for the `2`, `sudo update-grub` will do fine.  all this does is regenerate the */boot/grub/grub.cfg*

Comment: ha!  they are different commands.  *update-grub* is a shellscript that execs `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"` -- can you guess what *update-grub2* execs?  `update-grub "$@"` !!  so yeah, no need for the `2`.

Answer (score 1):

You have been hit by Bug #[570765](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/570765) , which is quite common for 10.04 adopters running Windows.

Loading the latest updates and rebooting will fix it.